# python arcade library, how to interact with other program

Tags: python, openai-gym, arcade

I'm currently trying to make a simple Python Arcade Game ("http://arcade.academy/")

I wrote a traffic simulation, and now I'm trying to develop another program, that can interact with it.

My Problem right now is, that I first don't know how to extract the pixels out of the Arcade Game and second how to 'steer' the Arcade Game automatically by another program. I only see 'on_mouse_click' and other similar hooks that could help me, but nothing towards a program. 
Maybe someone has an idea how the appropriate way to do such a thing is.

As background: I'm trying to make an OpenAI-gym out of this game, so that other 'AIs' can interact with with it.

Comment: kindly consider adding your effort in coding the same

Comment: removed unnecessary text